# Create MLCP log in text file with timestamp

Tags: log4j, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am ingesting data in MarkLogic using MLCP. I want to create log file as text file with timestamp.

My current code is writing the log into text file but the file name is not being created with the timestamp.

Below are the settings that I have in my `mlcp\conf\log4j.properties`:

```
log = D:/2019/mlcp-inspecdirect/Log
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

#Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${current.date.time}.log

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```